# Getting error message "unknown user name or bad password" while executing the procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, clrstoredprocedure

I am not able to execute the procedure using one shared folder path in sql server 2008.

Below is the piece of the stored procedure i am using:

> ```
> DECLARE @S AS NVARCHAR(36) = NEWID(),      @return_value int,     
> > @vcStatusMsg nvarchar(max),      @vcFileLocation nvarchar(500)
> >           EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[uspGenerateReport]
> >          @vcStatusMsg = @vcStatusMsg OUTPUT,
> >          @vcFileLocation = @vcFileLocation OUTPUT,
> >          @vcReportPath = N'\\demo\',
> >          @vcReportFileName = @S,
> >          @vcReportName = N'UserReport',
> >          @vcReportFolder = N'testReport',    @vcReportParamter = N'TEST_ID=10',      @vcReportServerUrl =
> > N'http://***/reportserver/reportexecution2005.asmx?wsdl',   
> > @vcServerDomain = N'***',    @vcServerUserName = N'***',    
> > @vcServerPassword = N'***'
> > 
> >  SELECT  @vcStatusMsg as N'@vcStatusMsg',    @vcFileLocation as
> > N'@vcFileLocation'
> ```

On executing the above procedure, i am getting the error message : 
 "System.IO.IOException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password"

Here i am trying to access the shared folder path.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message is due to the invalid path in the procedure.

The network path specified in the procedure requires authentication and sql server didn't get the valid credential to access the file so its creating the error message.

So the solution would be something as below,

Specify the credentials in procedure to access the shared folder.

or

If you are unable/ don't want to set the credential, just remove the password protection from the shared folder.

Hope this might help you.

Comment: Thanks ashis, i just removed the password protection from the shared folder and it worked for me.